# Webpack inline loader syntax: how to pass a boolean option?

Tags: webpack

This works (using [object syntax](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#inline)):

```js
import styles from '!style-loader?{"esModule":true}!css-loader!./style.css';
```

... however, this would not:

```js
import styles from '!style-loader?esModule=true!css-loader!./style.css';
```

> Invalid options object. Style Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
>
> - options.esModule should be a boolean.

I've tested `1`, `true` and even `"yes"`... no luck! Guess the url-style parsing is not taking into account the type conversion right?